# Does it make sense to use Spark to process completely independent sub-tasks?

Tags: rest, apache-spark, hadoop

Suppose my task can be divided into sub-tasks that can be executed independent of each other without communication or shared resources from beginning to end. Does it make sense to use Spark in this context? Or is there another solution that could be easier to implement on a hadoop cluster. Each of my sub-tasks makes a huge number of rest api calls and I'm not sure if Spark fits or not this kind of processing (if so, should I include my api service on each of the nodes?).

EDIT: suppose I have a billion of lines of data that can be grouped in thousands of groups. All the data cannot fit on one single machine. The n groups can be processed independantly from each other. Processing a group implies calculations and a single call to a REST api.

Comment: Hmmm, nothing standard to handle rest, you would need custom code. You could put custom REST code into a http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html. If you need lots of the working in parallel, then create multiple streams and union them.

Comment: I would suggest that you start with multi threading on a single machine, then multi processing, before convincing yourself that you really need distributed computing. The question is pretty vague, though... NiFi is a reasonable tool for REST request processing

Comment: Thanks @alexeipab and cricket_007. I edited my question, I hope it's less vague.

Comment: Would it cause 1 billion calls to the REST api? If not throttled down, it will cause a DDOS on REST api, had unfortunate experience with it in the past.

Comment: @alexeipab no, n calls where n is the number of groups (approximately tens of thousands "only")

Comment: So after group calculations your Dataset/Dataframe will be already partitioned and distributed across multiple executors and nodes. In order to access REST API you would need to write a UDF that takes columns as input and returns RESP API response, it is the easiest. In case of the REAT API requiring authentication, could be better to use Dataset.mapPartitions. In both cases custom REST API code will run inside each Dataset partition, aka in parallel.